# Powershell script with -ObjectEvent stops execution with | ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: json, powershell

I want to take action when a file is created. That part works fine.But I want to make a Rest API call and before format Json. I'm using | ConvertTo-Json.
No error, nothing happens?

`This is the code used:

```
$folder = 'C:\VMForTest_Files\IDM Process' # Enter the root path you want to monitor. 
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 

# Login to Rest API goes here

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'} 
 
$Action = {  
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
    Write-Host "1.The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
    Out-File -FilePath C:\VMForTest_Files\log\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
    
    $filecontent = Get-Content -Path ($folder + "\" + $name)
    $BaseDesc = $filecontent

    $BaseHead = "New IDM Event"
    $entityType = "u_EVE"
    $Body = @{ 
            entityType = $entityType
            BaseHeader = $BaseHead
            BaseDescription = $BaseDesc
            PriorityId = 7
            CategoryId = 7
            BaseEntityStatusId = 55
            AgentGroupId = 1
            BaseEntitySource = 1
            FormId = 79
    
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'POST' -Uri $saveentity -Headers $headers -Body $Body  # -StatusCodeVariable 'statusCode'


    Write-Host "99.The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
    
} 

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action $action
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ConvertTo-Json` and then `ConvertFrom-Json` on the output? Why not just pass the hashtable directly to `-Body`? And how do you know nothing happens? You never do anything with `$result`

Comment: Your request is also missing the headers

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit brief in description. To clarify, script runs fine until any | Convertxxx is used. Then it is just silet.

Comment: Sorry again, my mistake. I have tested everything. Now it is corrected to original code.

Comment: As I said, Rest API stuff are excluded, that part works fine.

Comment: Mathias, I know because I run all commands manually i.e not driven by event and then the Invoke-RestMethod works fine.

Answer (score 0):

- In your **`-Action` script block**, you're **trying to use variables that were initialized *outside* of it**, i.e. presumably variables created in the script that *called* `Register-ObjectEvent`.
- (Unless your script happens to be dot-sourced in the *global* scope), this **won't work**, because the **`-Action` script block runs in a *dynamic module***, and modules generally only see variables defined in the *global* scope.
- The solution is to **pass the required variable (values)** using, e.g., a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) to [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent)'s **`-MessageData` parameter**, which you can access from inside the `-Action` script block via `$Event.MessageData`.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75137553/45375) for an example.